# When are ふう and よう interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, formal-nouns

Lately ふう has been on my mind. Often it seems interchangeable with よう:

> 1. これを｛こんな**ふう**／この**よう**｝にしてください。 Please make it like this.
> 2. あれを｛どういう**ふう**／どの**よう**｝に解釈しますか。 In what way do you interpret that?
> 3. 家を出るとき、帰りにケーキを買ってきてという｛**ふう**／**よう**｝に言われました。 When I was about to leave, I was told to pick up some cake on the way back.

#### Questions

When ふう and よう are used in this way to mean "manner" or "like":

1. Are they always interchangeable?
2. Is there any difference in nuance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, as you already implicitly show in your examples, their modifiers are not interchangable.

> {こ/そ/あ/ど}んなふうに
> × {こ/そ/あ/ど}のふうに
> △ {こ/そ/あ/ど}んなように
> 　{こ/そ/あ/ど}のように

I think `ふう` means some manner freely picked out, whereas `よう` is a manner chosen from the possibilities set by the context. This difference parallels the English `what` vs. `which`.

> In what way did you do it?
> In which way did you do it?
>
> What kind of music do you like?
> Which kind of music do you like?

English `what` does not presuppose the possibilities whereas `which` requires a contextually specified set from which one is chosen (i.e., in linguistic terms, *discourse-linked*).

On top of that difference, `ふう` is less approximate than `よう`. To reflect the difference, I would translate your examples like this:

> これをこんなふうにしてください。
> 'Please make this kind of like this.
> これをこのようにしてください。
> 'Please make this (look) this way.

Comment: "ふう is less approximate than よう": Is this a typo?  Your translation suggests that ふう is more approximate.

Comment: @Amanda Maybe my English was wrong. I meant `よう` is more accurate than `ふう`.

Answer (score 4):

When I wrote my graduation thesis, I used このふうに. A friend corrected my Japanese, but told me he had left in all the ふう's as a nod to my personal style. He also said that ふう was inappropriate in a serious written style -- I should have used よう. By the time he told me this it was too late...

Comment: "it was too late ..." and what happened? Did you flunk? :P